# Quarkus multi-module cyclic reference problem

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, cdi, quarkus

This is my first project using Quarkus. 
I made a multi-module project and in the parent pom I have this module structure:

```xml
    <modules>
        <module>domain</module>
        <module>application</module>
        <module>client</module>
    </modules>
```

In my `domain` module I have my interfaces that are supposed to be implemented by the `application` and `client` modules. So I added the `<dependency>` in the `application` and the `client` modules, for implementing the `domain` interfaces. 
But when I want to add the `<dependency>` of the `application` module in my `domain` it doesn't work and when I build I have this error :

> [ERROR] [ERROR] The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between 'Vertex{label='com.test.name:application:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'}' and 'Vertex{label='com.test.name:domain:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'}' introduces to cycle in the graph com.test.name:domain:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --> com.test.name:application:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --> com.test.name:domain:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @
> [ERROR] The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between 'Vertex{label='com.test.name:application:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'}' and 'Vertex{label='com.test.name:domain:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'}' introduces to cycle in the graph com.test.name:domain:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --> com.test.name:application:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --> com.test.name:domain:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

I need this for dependency injection, my CDI container need to find the implementation to inject it. Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

The way I like to structure my projects is roughly as follows:

- Modules containing interfaces that are dependencies to other modules, similar to your `domain` module. They can be as fine or coarse grained as your design dictates. Examples are `app-service-interfaces` (e.g. interfaces for the business logic), `app-dao-interfaces` (interfaces for the DAO layer) etc.
- Modules containing the implementation of *a single* "interface" module. The implementation modules depend only on interface modules, obviously the one they implement and any other they need. E.g. the module `app-service-impl` depends and implement the `app-service-interfaces` module, but also depends on the `app-dao-interfaces` module because it needs access to the application's datastore facilities. The implementation of `app-dao-interfaces`  could be `app-dao-jpa`, if I choose to use JPA for the DAO layer. (Sidenote: keeping the interface modules free of dependencies to the actual technology used to implement them allows you to switch implementations easily.)

  - Neither the interface nor the implementation modules depend on the specific environment I intend to deploy on; Quarkus, JEE, Spring, Play, whatever.
- Finally, a **single** module, I call it the "assembly" module (term borrowed from our .Net colleagues) that depends on all the **implementation modules** I intend to deploy **plus the specific environment** (e.g. Quarkus for this case). This module may contain environment-specific implementations of some components (e.g. Microprofile Config implementation for the component that reads and holds the configuration in a Quarkus environment).

**2 final comments:**

- This is a proposal for *one* possible solution that works for me. I am sure there are plenty of others that work just as well; or this may not work for you for any reason!
- I have applied this principle in [this pet project](https://github.com/nikospara/realworld-v2) and have a relevant explanation [in this earlier, abandoned incarnation](https://github.com/nikospara/jee-thorntail-realworld-example-app/blob/master/README-Architecture.md#modules) of the same project. Beware, these are just scratch projects :)